# NGINX rewrite to Apache Mod-Rewrite

Tags: apache, nginx, mod-rewrite

I'm migrating a reverse proxy from NGINX to Apache, but can't wrap my head around how to convert the nginx rewrites to Apache mod rewrite.

Here's the relevant part of my nginx configuration:

```
    server { 
    listen           443 ssl;
    server_name localhost;


    #### REWRITE FOR APP PROXY ###
    rewrite ^/app-proxy/([^/]+?)/([^/]+?)/(.*)$ /$2/$1/$3 last;


    #### Final destination, SAL-ASSETS (STATIC FILES)
    location /sal-assets/ {
        alias       /var/www/sal-assets/;
        expires 30d;
    }

    #### Final destination TOMCAT & NG SERVE
    location / {
        proxy_pass          http://localhost:8080;
    }

    location /sal-frontnd/ {
        proxy_pass          http://localhost:4200;
    }

    location /sal-backend/ {
        proxy_pass          http://localhost:4200;
    }

}
```

Here's what I've got so far for Apache:

```
ProxyPass               /sal-frontend/     http://localhost:4200/sal-frontend/
ProxyPassReverse        /sal-frontend/     http://localhost:4200/sal-frontend/
ProxyPass               /sal-admin/     http://localhost:4200/sal-admin/
ProxyPassReverse        /sal-admin/     http://localhost:4200/sal-admin/
ProxyPass               /sal-backend/     http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse        /sal-backend/     http://localhost:8080/

<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule rewrite ^/app-proxy/([^/]+?)/([^/]+?)/(.*)$ /$2/$1/$3
```

Unfortunately my rewrite rule seems to be broken?

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 253 of C:/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf:
RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters
```

Would appreciate any hint.

Comment: first, remove `rewrite` word from `RewriteRule` line

Comment: maybe this tool helps you https://labs.gidix.de/nginx/

Comment: Appreciate the nginx converter, but it didn't work very well. :)

Answer (score 0):

The following finally worked for me:

```
<Directory />
RewriteEngine On
AllowOverride All
Require all denied
RewriteRule /app-proxy/([^/]+?)/([^/]+?)/(.*) /$2/$1/$3 [L,NC]
</Directory>
```

- Remove the "rewrite" from the RewriteRule line, as suggested by Dusan
- Move from  to
- Set AllowOverride All
- Remove ^ and $ from regex so that we have /app-proxy/([^/]+?)/([^/]+?)/(.*)
- Add [L,NC]